# How to set Netbeans Action Item filters to ignore third party folders?

Tags: netbeans, filter, netbeans-8, todo

I do not want to see errors and warnings for third party libraries in Netbeans Action Items list, so I created a filter as shown below:

[image: Filters to ignore vendor and node_modules folders]

The filter is turned on, but I still see many items from `node_modules` folders.
What am I doing wrong? How should the filter be configured to ignore everything coming from `node_modules` and `vendor` folders?

Answer (score 21):

A workaround for this is hiding `node_modules` from project tree

Steps:

1. Tools > Options Miscellaneous
2. Goto Files tab
3. Add "`node_modules`" to the `regex` in `Ignored Files Pattern` box. Here's an example:

```
^(node_modules|git.+|hgignore)$).*$
```

4. Save

Answer (score 2):

Just a reminder:
Ignoring folders will not display them any longer either and you wont be able to see it or search on it (until you enable it again of course). The filter for the extension works but will filter every single file with this extension, which problably isn't what you want either. 
If you just want to remove badges in a directory (recursive) without disabling it you just CAN'T.
This issue was reported to netbeans and they provide the same incomplete solutions.
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226954