# Netbeans background scanning project take long time and stuck at 100% scan

Tags: java, netbeans, loading

my first question...

I installed Netbeans 7.4 with JDK 1.8 on ny notebook (i3 2,4 ghz and 4gb ram) and make a simple project with 1 class for connection and 2 form (login and input form) with mysql jdbc driver. 
This problem appear after i designed my input form with this components :
26 labels
20 textfields
1 jtable
And 4 buttons
When i change my textfield variable name, ide got delay like 5 -  10 seconds after i clicked ither textfield. 
And when i completed code for 2 buttons on source section tab, color highlighter and error checking (red and yellow line on right side) got delayed 3 - 5 minutes, and not appear at all if i reopen my project. I only opened just 1 project at time and running xampp on background. 
Now, i cant edit ny project after all on netbeans.. 
I alrrady look to enable auto scan project setting it uncheck. I usually use netbeans on offline condition. 
I tried to reinstall Netbeans but not work at all.

Please give some solutions, I really apreciate it. Thank you. 
And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but as I was myself looking for a solution with this issue, I get there fast.

In my case :
The scanning of the project was too long because one of my sub-folder in my project was a tileset of picture (several thousands pictures).

I ignored this folder in the project properties ("Ignored Folders").

Since then, no more problem : The project scan was done fast and well.

Comment: I noticed no info on how to do this so see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31891348/1236837