# why red 'Exclamation Mark' appears on project after installing puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, netbeans, puppeteer

Whenever I install puppeteers in my netbeans project, A red Exclamation Mark appears on my project name which is actually representing error in 'install.js' (node Modules/puppeteers/install.js). How to resolve this?
[image]

> Error

[image]

Comment: What error message is NetBeans giving you? Can you hover over the line numbers to see the error message?

Comment: It displays '' invalid return statement' ', js parsing error.

Comment: Okay, this is more an "information" to you than an error in your project. You should set Netbeans to ignore your `node_modules` folder (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is shown as a `return` statement is normally only expected in functions (but actually also valid outside of them). Therefore, the netbeans syntax checker tells you that this is invalid code (although it is valid).

Most likely, you want Netbeans to [ignore the node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31891348/5627599), as bad code inside any of these modules should not be shown as an error in your project.