# Exclude TODO from specific files in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, comments, netbeans-8, todo

Is there a way to filter out or ignore the TODOs coming from specific files?

My todo list is overrun with todos coming from libraries rather than my own code. Since the libraries are included in my project, filtering by project doesn't solve the issue.

I could delete those todos or rename them, but I'd rather set Netbeans to ignore them if possible.

Comment: Maybe this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721090/how-to-set-netbeans-action-item-filters-to-ignore-third-party-folders ?

Comment: Vadim Kotov Thanks. The downside of hiding the folders completely and being unable to consult them when needed is a bit too much just for the sake of hiding todos. In the end, I just renamed all the library "@TODO" to "@TO-DO" using regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to rename the @TODOs in the libraries to @TO-DO, which prevents them from being automatically added to my todo list.

It's a bit hackish (especially considering I'll have to do it again every time I update said libraries), but it isn't a problem big enough to warrant spending more time on it.